# Joint Density Function Acturial exam help

Tags: probability

I'm given a join density function of $f(x,y) = 2(x+y)$ on the region where the density is positive. X is a basic policy that is required to be bought for the supplemental policy Y to be purchased. The question is "Given that 10% of the employees buy the basic policy, what's the probability that fewer than 5% buy the supplemental policy.

I have $P(0.05>Y | x=0.1)$. I know $h(y|x)=f(x,y)/g(x)$. I'm confused as to what the limits of integration are to find $g(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure you're quoting the question correctly?  What does it mean for $X$ to be a basic policy?  Could $X$ be a number of employees that buy the basic policy?

Comment: $2(x+y)$ is positive over a very large region. The integral of $2(x+y)$ over that region is infinite, so we do not have a density function.

Comment: I think the region is $x \in [0,1]$, $y \in [0,x]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X$ is a random variable representing the fraction of customers buying the basic policy.  $Y$ is the fraction buying the supplemental policy.  Because customers buying supplemental must buy basic, $Y \le X$.  Thus, the region of interest is $0 \le y \le x \le 1$.

The sought-after probability is then

$$P(Y<0.05\, | X=0.1) = \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^{0.05} dy \, 2 (0.1+y)}{\displaystyle \int_0^{0.1} dy \, 2 (0.1+y)} = \frac{0.0125}{0.03} = \frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you. I see there's an easier way to do it than what I was trying to do. I was integrating g(x) from 0 to 1-x instead of just 0 to x. That gave me the correct answer as well. Need to get those limits correct or nothing works.

Comment: @Matt: getting the answer right is important, but it all starts with accurately understanding what the problem is about.  You need to clearly and succinctly state what the random variables represent.  Note that I had no access to the problem you stated (incorrectly), but deduced what the range was and therefore what the random variables *had to* represent?  It is crucial you get this right before attempting any other aspect of the problem.